# Confusing SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select

First I will show you example tables that my issue pertains to, then I will ask the question.

```
[my_fruits]
fruit_name   |   fruit_id   | fruit_owner   |   fruit_timestamp
----------------------------------------------------------------
Banana       |   3          |  Timmy        |   3/4/11
Banana       |   3          |  Timmy        |   4/1/11
Banana       |   8          |  Timmy        |   5/2/11
Apple        |   4          |  Timmy        |   2/1/11
Apple        |   4          |  Roger        |   3/4/11
```

Now I want to run a query that only selects fruit_name, fruit_id, and fruit_owner values.  I only want to get one row per fruit, and the way I want it to be decided is by the latest timestamp.  For example the perfect query on this table would return:

```
[my_fruits]
fruit_name   |   fruit_id   | fruit_owner   |
----------------------------------------------
Banana       |   8          |  Timmy        |
Apple        |   4          |  Roger        |
```

I tried the query:

```
select max(my_fruits.fruit_name) keep 
    (dense_rank last order by my_fruits.fruit_timestamp) fruit_name,
       my_fruits.fruit_id, my_fruits.fruit_owner 
from my_fruits 
group by my_fruits.fruit_id, my_fruits.fruit_owner
```

Now the issue with that is returns basically distinct fruit names, fruit ids, and fruit owners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Oracle 9i+, use:

```
SELECT x.fruit_name,
       x.fruit_id,
       x.fruit_owner
  FROM (SELECT mf.fruit_name,
               mf.fruit_id,
               mf.fruit_owner,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mf.fruit_name
                                      ORDER BY mf.fruit_timestamp) AS rank
          FROM MY_FRUIT mf) x
 WHERE x.rank = 1
```

Most databases will support using a self join on a derived table/inline view:

```
SELECT x.fruit_name,
       x.fruit_id,
       x.fruit_owner
  FROM MY_FRUIT x
  JOIN (SELECT t.fruit_name,
               MAX(t.fruit_timestamp) AS max_ts
          FROM MY_FRUIT t
      GROUP BY t.fruit_name) y ON y.fruit_name = x.fruit_name
                              AND y.max_ts = x.fruit_timestamp
```

However, this will return duplicates if there are 2+ fruit_name records with the same timestamp value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want one row per fruit name, you have to group by fruit_name.

```
select fruit_name,
       max(my_fruits.fruit_id) keep 
          (dense_rank last order by my_fruits.fruit_timestamp) fruit_id,
       max(my_fruits.fruit_owner) keep 
          (dense_rank last order by my_fruits.fruit_timestamp) fruit_owner
from my_fruits 
group by my_fruits.fruit_name
```

How you want to deal with tie-breaks is a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try a subquery:

```
select a.fruit_name, a.fruit_id, a.fruit_owner
from my_fruits a
where a.fruit_timestamp =
 (select max(b.fruit_timestamp)
  from my_fruits b
  where b.fruit_id = a.fruit_id)
```

Comment: This will return duplicates if there are 2+ fruit_name records with the same timestamp value

Comment: Yes, but it will correctly return 2 records if 2 different fruit_owners have the latest fruit_timestamp.

Comment: Which isn't what the OP wants

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by finding out the list of (fruit_name, fruit_timestamp) which are of interest to you, and then grouping that "table" with the actual fruit table and retrieving the other values.

```
SELECT fruit_and_max_t.fruit_name, 
       my_fruits.fruit_id,
       my_fruits.fruit_owner
FROM my_fruits, 
  ( SELECT fruit_name, MAX(fruit_timestamp) AS max_timestamp
    FROM my_fruits
    GROUP BY fruit_name) AS fruit_and_max_t,
WHERE fruit_and_max_t.max_timestamp = my_fruits.fruit_timestamp
  AND fruit_and_max_t.fruit_name    = my_fruits.fruit_name
```

This assumes that there are not multiple entries in the table with the same value of (fruit_name, fruit_timestamp), i.e. that tuple (pair) act like a unique identifier.

Comment: I'd vote for ANSI-92 syntax, which this is not -- it's ANSI-89.  But then it'd be identical to what I already posted in my answer...

Comment: @OMG Ponies - True about the syntax, and true that I didn't see your answer when posting my own. I personally find the old syntax easier to understand but maybe that's just because I'm used to it!

Comment: ANSI-89 syntax isn't a good habit to have, being without OUTER join support.

Comment: I fear this debate could get heated ;) .. I see your point, however in this case there are no OUTER joins.